# Update UADetector resources

Tags: java, browser, user-agent

UADetector last version is from Nov 2014, it's uses a XML file uas.xml which contains all the User-Agents known to him.

The latest obviously doesn't recognize Edge browser, and categorize it as Chrome.

The format of uas.xml for example -

```
<browser>
                <id>2</id>
                <type>0</type>
                <name>SeaMonkey</name>
                <url><![CDATA[http://www.seamonkey-project.org/]]></url>
                <company><![CDATA[Mozilla Foundation]]></company>
                <url_company><![CDATA[http://www.mozilla.org/]]></url_company>
                <icon>seamonkey.png</icon>
                <browser_info_url>/list-of-ua/browser-detail?browser=SeaMonkey</browser_info_url>
</browser>
```

Is there a way to update the resources to recognize new browsers correctly?

Answer (score 0):

https://udger.com/resources/ua-list. It seems the UADetector library uses a third party source. Perhaps you can try to see if it helps. IT's available as part of the README file in the same github repository.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Soundararajan, but the list doesn't help me since I will need to manually transform it to the XML format.